# Chrome Packaged App TOKEN_MISSING_ERROR

Tags: in-app-purchase, chrome-web-store

I have a Chrome packaged application that I am testing to add in-app purchases. When running the application from my own account querying `getSkuDetails` works fine. However, when running it from another test account, it returns `TOKEN_MISSING_ERROR`. I cannot find any google developer documentation to help me progress this. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Not making any progress here. AS an alternative approach does anyone know if you can use Paypal to make in-app purchases? I am taking no server side PHP stuff here, the java script in the Chrome Packaged App must be able to invoke the pay-pal payment mechanism and receive two callbacks one for success and one for failure.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that this problem is related to the Chrome browser not being logged in. I ran into this same issue on my test machine's Chrome browser, however, after I logged Chrome into my Google Account, it returned success and I could also open the buy window.